# Angular, image not found (GET 404)

Tags: html, angular

I'm at the moment trying to embed an image to my angular project but I'm getting an error that the immage can not be found.

```
GET http://localhost:4200/logo.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

I have tried to embed the image with the standard method just like this

```
<img src="../logo.svg">
```

I have checked the source and also tried other file formats.

Comment: where is the image located in your project?

Comment: At the moment in the "src" folder of my project, but I've also tried other folders and nothing is working.

Comment: put it in assets folder. !

Comment: Are you using `angular-cli`?

Comment: Is your server running on Ubuntu? If yes, use `chmod` command to update read and write permission of the file. _(hint: in case you are not familiar with Ubuntu and `chmod`, google it up)_

Comment: @torazaburo yes I'm using angular-cli

Comment: @Path Ghiya thank you, that solved the problem :)

Comment: @ParthGhiya ..I tried putting the image in the assets folder...it creates the correct link to the image but still gives the error saying - "img not found". I am giving the correct path now but it generates this error -  http://xxx.xxx.xx.x/src/assets/logo.jpg 404 (Not Found)...do you know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

@Parth Ghiya commented the answer to my question. I had to put the image to the /src/assets folder. Angular is now able to find the image.

Comment: I found this worked if I also put the url as /assets/whatever rather than a relative address like ../../assets/whatever

Answer (score 17):

Static resources (images, fonts, json files...etc.) should be added to the *assets* folder. By default, whatever you put in the assets folder you can access it directly from the browser and queried through an HTTP request:

```js
src
 ┣ app
 ┃ ┣ core
 ┃ ┣ shared
 ┃ ┣ app-routing.module.ts
 ┃ ┣ app.component.ts
 ┃ ┣ app.module.ts
 ┣ assets
 ┃ ┣ img
 ┃ ┃ ┗ logo.png // this will be served
 ┣ static
 ┃ ┃ ┗ background.png // this won't be served unless you add it to the assets array
 ┣ environments
 ┣ styles
 ┣ favicon.ico
 ┣ index.html
 ┣ main.ts
 ┣ polyfills.ts
```

Now if you want to use the `logo.png` image that is the `assets/img` folder you can do that like this:

```html
<img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo">   <!-- OK  :)   ->
<img src="static/background.png" alt="logo"> <!-- Not OK :(->
```

if you want to use the `background.png` that is inside the `static` folder, you need to include the `static` folder in the assets array inside the `angular.json` file:

```json
...
"assets": [
   "src/favicon.ico",
   "src/assets",
   "src/static"
],
...
```

```html
<img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo">   <!-- OK :) ->
<img src="static/background.png" alt="logo"> <!-- OK :) ->
```

I like to highlight that is better NOT to :

- use the `src/` to reference your static resources (images, ...etc.).
- use the relative paths `../logo.png`.

Answer (score 6):

ERROR

```
<img src="src/static/images/logo.png" alt="" width="49" height="35">
```

**SOLUTION** (take out the src)

```
<img src="static/images/logo.png" alt="" width="49" height="35">
```

*be happy and "welcome to the scatman's world!"..*

Comment: This worked fine.   using "../../src/assets"  gives error.

Answer (score 4):

For me size was the only problem.
When I changed size now it is displaying 
My image path 
/src/assets/images/products/white.jpg

my image url is :
/assets/images/products/white.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you are at your app.component.html if you want to use a picture from your src folder use:

```
<img src="../../src/logo.svg">
```

Each `../` takes you one folder up

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I understood that you can update angular.json in assets property. In my case, I added "src/img" for get a new folder position and works fine.

```
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/img"
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

in `angular.jso`n add the path in assets. Example below.

```
"assets": [
"src/favicon.ico",
"src/assets",
"src/assets/images"
```

in the `component.html` you add this

```
  <img [attr.src]="'assets/images/logo.png'" alt="logo">
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a new folder and angular does not find my images.

```
<img src="assets/image/imageName.jpg" >
```

So, I deleted the folder: .angular and restart the build with `ng serve`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried all the solutions in the comments and still haven't found a solution, try this:

if your assets folder is in your app folder like this.
/src/app/assets/img/...
Try extracting the assets folder from the app folder. Your path is like this:

/src/assets/img/...

But in angular, you don't need to type '/src'. Just type this:

/assets/img/...

Answer (score 0):

solution

> "assets": [
> "src/favicon.ico",
> "src/assets",
> "src/assets/images",
> "src/assets/styles"
> ],

just add full path

Answer (score -1):

The solution from Brian worked for me

> > 
>
> SOLUTION (take out the src)
>
> ```
> <img src="static/images/logo.png" alt="" width="49" height="35">
> ```

Answer (score -2):

First you need to add image in **/src/assets/** folder. Then type like this.

This is works for me!

**htmlfile.html**

```
<img src="assets/image/imageName.jpg" >
```